# windowsphone cordova image tag is not loading

Tags: image, cordova, windows-phone-8

i am developing an app that take image from public government website and render it in my app. This not AJAX, just  and src.
The contents are 100% public and free. It works fine with ios and android , but with wp8, the image just doesnt want to load. 
I have try to render it in canvas, but it seems this is due to internal settings in WP

my example code is as simple as this

```
<img src='http://example-gov.jpeg'/>
```

Comment: try whitelisting the url on the config.xml

Comment: mm.. how exactly to do it? i tried to do whitelist from angularjs, but it still the same.

Comment: what about googling whitelist cordova?

Comment: What happens if you keep image inside img folder and access , does it work or not?

Answer (score 1):

whitelist external URL

open your `config.xml` and edit this line

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Comment: that's not a good idea if you worry about security in your app, but could be good for testing if the whitelist is the problem

Comment: well, from googling this is the first method i tried, but it's still not working. I think there is C# internal method. but I am not familiar with C#.